# SED Escape in bash script

Tags: bash, sed

My tempfile.txt has below contents [Typical Cisco Configuration File]

```
interface GigabitEthernet1/11
 no ip address
 shutdown
 rmon collection stats 6010 owner monitor
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/12
 no ip address
 shutdown
 rmon collection stats 6011 owner monitor
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/13
 no ip address
 shutdown
 rmon collection stats 6012 owner monitor
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/14
 no ip address
 shutdown
 rmon collection stats 6013 owner monitor
!
```

I am trying to loop through to do some operation on each block
Example

```
interface GigabitEthernet1/14 --> start of interface block
     no ip address
     shutdown
     rmon collection stats 6013 owner monitor
    ! --> end of interface block
```

I have another file which has below data intefaces.txt

```
interface GigabitEthernet1/11
interface GigabitEthernet1/12
interface GigabitEthernet1/13
interface GigabitEthernet1/14
```

Now want to do some changes in each block thats why I am trying to access block in loop via

```
while read line
do
sed -n '/$line/,/!/p' tempfile.txt # this should get me block
#code for doing some changes in block
done < interfaces.txt
```

Now since my $line will be one of line of interfaces.txt eg: `interface GigabitEthernet1/11`

how can I escape `/` as I am doing in loop & my interfaces will always contain / character

Comment: `sed -e 's,/,\\/,'`?

Comment: Can you give some more detail on what you like to do.  Do you like to update an config file with data from another file?  Cisco Works should do all this, but that is not a simple solution.

Comment: @Jotne: I am parsing it to make XML & use it on some XML API's of SDN

Comment: Every time you write a shell loop just to manipulate text you have the wrong approach. Just use awk, it's what it was invented to do by the same guys who invented the shell to call it from. What is the point of that second file? Is it to restrict the operations you want to perform to only SOME of the interfaces? If it's just a list of all of them then it's not useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tell `sed` which character to use in place of `/` in the search by prefixing it with a backslash:

```
sed -n "\@${line}@,/!/p" ...
```

Comment: `-bash: !/p": event not found ` how to get rid of this error

Comment: The prejudiced way is to say "get rid of the `csh` junk from `bash`", but that isn't wholly trivial.  Surround the `!` in single quotes instead of double quotes: `sed -n "\@${line}@,"'/!/p' …`.

Comment: Yep! I realized that. Thanks

Comment: Bang expansion is quite useful, so I'd just as soon not get rid of it.  But the way it follows its own set of unique-snowflake quoting rules is patently ridiculous.

Answer (score 2):

To work with block of text, use `gnu awk` (due to multiple characters in RS)

```
awk -vRS="interface" '/1\/13/ {print RS $0}' file
interface GigabitEthernet1/13
 no ip address
 shutdown
 rmon collection stats 6012 owner monitor
!
```

Here you get all of info for interface `1/13`

---

You can prevent the escaping of `/` by getting it in as a variable.

```
awk -vRS="interface" -vtest="1/13" '$0~test {print RS $0}'
interface GigabitEthernet1/13
 no ip address
 shutdown
 rmon collection stats 6012 owner monitor
!
```

Comment: @MarkReed Should be ok to read it from another file as OP need.  Se also a workaround to use `/` without escaping in `awk`

Comment: Thank you - I didn't know awk's `~` operator would take a string in place of a regex. Useful tip.

Comment: Thank you, even this helped somewhat

Comment: You should mention this will only work in GNU awk for multi-char RS. Other awks will use `i` for the value of RS given the above (once you add a space between `-v` and `RS` - no space is also gawk-specific).

Comment: @MarkReed it's not that `~` is taking a string **in place of** a regexp exactly, its that `~` can work on a regexp specified as a regexp literal `/re/` or as a dynamic regexp `"re"`. They're both regexps but the latter requires double-escaping of meta-characters, etc. when appropriate and can be concatenated with other strings/variables to form larger dynamic regexps. See http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Computed-Regexps for details.

Comment: @EdMorton Did forget it, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

In `bash`, you can use the parameter global replace operator, `${varname//old/new}`, to replace the slashes with backslashed slashes, like this:

```
while read line; do
   sed -n "/${line//\//\/\/}/",'/!/p' tempfile.txt | # do stuff
done <interfaces.txt
```

... but Holy Leaning Toothpicks, Batman!  I would go with @JonathanLeffler's solution of changing sed's search delimiter.